# Como verificar se uma tabela existe no Banco de dados SQL Server 2005 e se ela não existir criar ela e as colunas

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi-7

Como verificar se uma tabela existe no Banco de dados SQL Server 2005 e se ela não existir criar ela e as colunas.
O objetivo desse processo e criar essa rotina para quando eu precisar criar um campo novo na minha aplicação, eu colocar ele dentro desse processo, para nao correr o risco de em algum momento gerar um erro por estar faltando uma tabela ou campo.

Answer (score 12):

Existe a view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` que possibilita você fazer a verificação, e uma das vantagens dela é que ela é definida por padrão em diferentes bases de dados e versões do SGBD.

Veja como implementar:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
BEGIN
    --Faça algo aqui...
END
```

Fonte: [Check if table exists in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/167680/5429980).

Answer (score 3):

Outro modo interessante é verificar pela função Object_Id no Sql Server 2008 tenho certeza que funciona, no 2005 terá que fazer o teste.

```
if object_id('TABELA') is null
begin
     create Tabela (
            campo tipo,
            campo2 tipo
     )
end
```

Para verificar se a coluna existe, ela vai listar todas as colunas da tabela desejada, só implementar a lógica para ver se o campo que deseja criar já não existe na mesma

```
select b.name as 'Coluna'
  from sys.tables a
  join sys.columns b on a.object_id = b.object_id
 where a.name = 'tabela'
```